# error: not well-formed (invalid token) in old source code newly compiled in Studio

Tags: xml

I originally published an application back around 2011.  I've been "away" from developing since then due to medical issues but am now trying to get back into it.  I see the world has changed while I was away.  Now using Studio instead of eclipse.  My build is returning: "error: not well-formed (invalid token)" but does not point at a specific line in my main.xml which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quote"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket `>` on your root element.

Comment: The "root element" being Linear Layout?  So you would like to see: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" changed to <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">?

Comment: By root element, you mean the Linear Layout? So you would like me to change <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">?